# How to get output from a function?

Tags: r, function, return-value

I added the code `list(Root = xnew, Value = f(xnew), Iterations=i)` to the end of the following function to get Root, Value, and Iterations all printed out, but I got only one value, which was `xnew`. How can I correct this problem?

```
fixedpoint <- function(fun, x0, tol=1e-08, max.iter=40){
    xold <- x0
    xnew <- fun(xold)
    for (i in 1:max.iter) {
    xold <- xnew
    xnew <- f(xold)
    if ( abs((xnew-xold)) < tol )
        return(xnew)
    }
    stop("max iterations = 20")
}
```

Comment: Notice the return statement that is already present in the function...

Comment: I put "(Root = xnew, Value = f(xnew), Iterations=i)" inside return but got a warning message:In return(Root = x2, Value = f(x2), Iterations = i) :multi-argument returns are deprecated.

Comment: return(list(Root = xnew, Value = f(xnew), Iterations=i))

Answer (score 0):

Answer go out to N8TRO.

You should concatenate `fixedpoint` return values into a `list`. Please see as below:

```
fixedpoint <- function(fun, x0, tol = 1e-08, max.iter = 40) {
  xold <- x0
  xnew <- fun(xold)
  for (i in 1:max.iter) {
    xold <- xnew
    xnew <- f(xold)
    if (abs(xnew-xold) < tol) {
        return(list(Root = xnew, Value = f(xnew), Iterations = i))
  }
  stop("max iterations = 20")
}
```